# How do I get the value of a selected bootstrap dropdown-item using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have the following bootstrap dropdown.

I try to get into the console.log the value of the selected dropdown-item with jquery. I can console.log the text, using the below code but for some reason when I change `.text()` to `.val()`, I don't get the value/

```js
$('.dropdown-item').click(function() {
  console.log( $(this).text() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action='/' method='get'>
              <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-sm" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Select Date
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                  
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" value="1">March 16 to 19 - CANCELLED</a>
                  
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" value="2">March 21 and 22 - REVISED</a>
                  
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" value="3">March 23 to 26 - REVISED</a>
                  
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" value="4">March 28 and 29</a>
                  
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" value="5">March 30 to April 2 - REVISED</a>
                  
                </div>
             </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Probably your aproach is not the best. But here how you can get the value: 

console.log( $(this).attr("value") );

Comment: @KevynKlava That did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Anchors can't have a value attribute. Try a sata attribute instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I had to use the .attr method like below. Thank you to @KevynKlava for the answer

```
$('.dropdown-item').click(function() {
  console.log( $(this).attr('value') );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/vkLr7zhe/ use data attribute as solution . I put in fiddle

```
$('.dropdown-item').click(function() {
  console.log( $(this).data("id") );
});






<a class="dropdown-item"data-id="1" href="#" value="1">March 16 to 19 - CANCELLED</a>
```